# Cannot edit input element initialised using MathField

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mathquill

The following input element initialised using MathField is non-editable.

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="question" id="question" style="border:0px;" placeholder="* Question" type="text"/>
```

and in the controller

```
MQ.MathField($scope.answerSpan, {
    handlers: {
        edit: function() {
            $scope.answerSpan1 = answerMathField.latex();
            if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest')
                $scope.$apply();

        }
    }
});
```

Are MathQuill and AngularJS interfering with each other?

Comment: can you post plunker, to get more idea?